# SublimeText2 Code Folding Level 4

Tags: ide, sublimetext2

Admittedly, I only spent a short time searching for why this is happening.

For some reason this morning my SublimeText2 stopped allowing me to fold level 4 (nested) blocks.

```
function function_name1 (argument) {
  function function_name2 (argument) {
    function function_name3 (argument) {
      function function_name4 (argument) {
        function function_name5 (argument) {
          function function_name6 (argument) {
            function function_name7 (argument) {
              // body...
              // 
              // 
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can fold all levels with the exception of level 4 (function_name4) block. This has been working in the past, am I right?

Comment: I can fold all levels of your example code in ST2 on XP...

Comment: Nope it is still a problem that I just deal with at the moment. Too busy to do any digging into it.